# Why is Thevenin Voltage of this circuit equal to the voltage source?

Tags: impedance, inductance, thevenin, norton, equivalent-circuit

I am well aware that Thevenin voltage is equal to the open circuit voltage at the end of the circuit.

The circuit information are:  \$_\$=50∠0 **V**, \$_\$=5∠0 **A**, \$_1\$=10 **Ω**, \$_2=10\$ **Ω**, and \$_=10i\$ **Ω**.

The circuit diagram is this:

[image]

My question is why is thevenin voltage equal to source voltage here. There should be a voltage drop cross R1 right? Can anyone help with a clear information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From KCL at the top-middle node:
$$I_2 = I_1 + I_B$$

From KVL at the leftmost loop:
$$V_A  -V_{R_1} - V_{R_2} = 0$$
$$V_A - I_1 \cdot R_1 - I_2 \cdot R_2 = 0$$
$$V_A - I_1 \cdot R_1 - (I_1 + I_B) \cdot R_2 = 0$$

Solving for \$I_1\$, after substituting the rest of the variables, yields:
$$I_1=0[A]$$

Therefore, there is no voltage drop across R1, and the Thevenin voltage is equal to \$V_A\$.

Answer (score 2):

> *My question is why is thevenin voltage equal to source voltage here.
> There should be a voltage drop cross R1 right? Can anyone help with a
> clear information on this?*

In this particular example, there is no current passing through \$R_1\$ because of the presence of \$I_B\$ and \$R_2\$. Coincidentally, they produce the same 50 volts terminal voltage as \$V_A\$. Thus, no current flows through \$R_1\$ and, the Thevenin voltage is wholly determined by \$I_B\$ and \$R_2\$ (which happens to be coincidentally the same value as \$V_A\$).

Answer (score 2):

In general, for this topology, \$V_{Th}\ne V_S\$.

The equality exists for these values only. Change any of \$V_S\$, \$R_2\$, or \$I_B\$ will effect an inequality instead.

Change any two such that \$V_S=R_2 I_B\$ then the equality will remain.